# Simultaneus Multicolor for Letter using Latex

Tags: tikz-styles, latex3

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1.3cm}


\begin{document}
\centering
{\Huge Markallaa}\\
\vspace{1.1cm}
{\huge (Harawii)}

\end{document}
```

The desired output is as follow:

[image: desired]

Comment: Tikz Fading Library could be the solution?